# Between Ubuntu 18.04, OSX 11.4 and Windows 7+, which is the easiest/able to run on a Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, macos

I'm currently looking for a low-cost personal computer that can run some software, and currently I've found the Raspberry Pi to be the best option. System requirements are either a Windows 7+, OSX 11.4 or Ubuntu 18.04, and I don't know which would be easier to run.

Comment: Only one of those can run on a Pi. What is the question?

Comment: well, which one is it? i haven't had any experience with the pi so i have no clue which of the OSes work

Comment: Whats wrong with Raspbian Buster?

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply the answer is Ubuntu. The others don't work on the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the question of a lot of amateur people in Raspberry Pi.

The processor is important if you want to run different OPERATING SYSTEM. There are some limitations. As an example, it's better to install OSX on Apple products instead of Windows. The OSX is fit on the processor of Apple products and is much more compatible.

The same on Raspberry Pi which the processor is ARM (`armhf`=>`32bit`, `arm64`=>`64bit`), you should install Linux operating system. As you know, Linux has plenty of distribution like "Ubuntu", "Debian", "Fedora", "OpenSUSE", "CentOS", etc.

However, the Raspberry Pi foundation said you should install Raspbian (Which is Debian ported for Raspberry Pi). Check out more:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

> Raspbian is our official operating system for all models of the
>   Raspberry Pi. Download it here, or use NOOBS, our easy installer for
>   Raspbian and more.

In conclusion, you can Install Raspbian or Ubuntu easily with NOOBS but you should install directly the OS. Additionally, check [this link -"*WOA-Deployer-Rpi*"](https://github.com/WOA-Project/WOA-Deployer-Rpi) out for running Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi boards.

Answer (score 1):

Depends- are you thinking of a Pi-zero or a 4Gb Pi-4B?  There is a big difference.
You mentioned "system requirements"-  Who or what is asking for these requirements? If it's a teacher, ask them if the latest Raspian will be satisfactory.
 Raspian is a "fork" of Debian, just as Ubuntu 18.04 is.
As well, Raspbian is configured SPECIFICALLY for the ARM architecture / processor hardware on a Raspberry.
Note that as a fellow Linux system, Raspbian will run just about anything that Ubuntu will.

I've tried the Ubuntu 64-bit on my Pi4B, but it appeared kinda buggy - perhaps "clumsy" is a better word - so I reverted to Raspian "Stretch" which installs like charm.

If you're concerned about costs, don't forget about other system requirements for a Raspberry-  purchases such a wireless keyboard and mouse, and a monitor or a TV with HDMI input.

Comment: You reverted to Raspbian Stretch. That's OK but oldstable. You should suggest to install Raspbian Buster for a new installation.